# How do I make my header Full Width for Mobile & desktop? HTML EMAIL

Tags: html, css, mobile, header, width

I'm almost done with this email, but the only issue is now on mobile the header isn't full width. I am trying to make the header image the full width of the (mobile) device screen but I keep running into a blocker and it only partially fills the screen above the text. I cant use  since this is for an email template, so all CSS has to be inline. How do I make the header full-width and centered for mobile?

EDIT : I noticed as soon as I posted this that the desktop width also wasn't full. . .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Saira:ital,wght@0,400;0,600;0,700;0,725;0,800;0,900;1,300;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>NASCAR Fan Email</title>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; background: url('https://www.nascar.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2022/01/13/NASCAR_FanCouncil_NewsletterExample_02X-1_Background-scaled.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;   -webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover; font-family: 'Saira', sans-serif;">


  <table class="outer" style="margin: 0 auto; border:0; border-spacing: 0; align-items: center;
        font-family: Stainless-Bold; color: black; width: 100%;">
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 0;">
        <table style=" border-spacing: 0; width: 100%; border:0;">
          <tr>
            <td class="fanCouncil" style=" text-align: center;  width: 100%;">
              <img class="fanHeader" src="https://www.nascar.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2022/01/13/NASCAR_FanCouncil_NewsletterExample_02X-1_Header-scaled.jpg" alt="Fan Email" width="100%">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <table style="border:0;">
      <tr>
        <td class=" photoText " style="position: absolute; top: 600px; left: 130px;">
          <p style="
                line-height: 2.2;
                max-width: 1200px;
                font-size: 40px; font-family: 'Saira', sans-serif;" class=" entryText ">Hello, <br> <br> We’d like to invite you to participate in a short survey about this past weekend’s races. This survey should take less than 5 minutes and will be open through Wednesday, August 25. We want to know what you think!
          </p>

          <a href="http://www.nascarfancouncil.com/c/al/5YVqVGmxA5g98218UalK-Bl/5bn1vdLmXO68WPcydpyM7J " class=" clickStart " style=" font-size: 40px; font-weight: 1000;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                text-decoration: none; color: black;">Click here to Start </a>
          <p style="
                line-height: 2.2;
                max-width: 1200px;
                font-size: 40px; font-family: 'Saira', sans-serif;" class=" unableText "> If you are unable to click the link, please copy and past the full URL below into your browser:</p>

          <a style=" font-size: 40px; color: black; font-family: 'Saira', sans-serif;" href="http://www.nascarfancouncil.com/c/al/5YVqVGmxA5g98218UalK-Bl/5bn1vdLmXO68WPcydpyM7J " class=" copyLink ">http://www.nascarfancouncil.com/c/al/5YVqVGmxA5g98218UalK-Bl/5bn1vdLmXO68WPcydpyM7J</a>

          <p style="line-height: 2.2; max-width: 1200px; font-size: 40px; font-family: 'Saira', sans-serif;" class=" thankYou ">Thank you!<br>Official NASCAR Fan Council</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </table>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with your structure and the styling.
Your structure with nested tables isn't exactly needed and that's part of the cause of your problem.

table

> table (image)

> table (text)

In the second table you use a position absolute, so that element is taken out of the normal flow. Your first table still has a 100% width, it's the screens width, but your second table with the position absolute is on some screens a lot wider then the screen so you have to scroll to the left. Hence more then 100%. But your first table with the header was just 100%. There's your problem.

**My recommanded solution:**

All you need is 2 rows filled with the data (Even one row would work) and not use a position absolute. Like the structure below. But then you would need to replace some more code.

table

> tr
>
> > ```
> > td with image
> > ```

> tr
>
> > ```
> > td with text
> > ```

**Quick fix:**

Just give the header a position:fixed so it can't move anymore and is always at the position that you want it. But with this solution your header will stay in the view. Scrolling horizontal (to fix your problem) but as well when scrolling vertical. So that kinda changes it.

```
<td class="fanCouncil" style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; z-index: 999; text-align: center;  width: 100%;">
```